# how to create a button maker with wordpress shortcode

Tags: wordpress, button, shortcode

i want to create a shortcode functions that creates various buttons...
in my shortcode tag, i specify the properties that i want like bg-color, size, and ... like this:

```
[my-btn size="small" bg-color="#002861" border-radius="2"]click me[/my-btn]
```

in my shortcode function how i can apply these styles to my btn.
for example user enter background red for button. how i can apply red background and return button...
or i have 2 size of buttons: small or big. how i can set width: 100px for small and 200px for big?
thanks...

Comment: Welcome to SO community. can post your shortcode script?

Comment: not write it yet!

Comment: you can check by if condition to add style by `shortcode_atts`

Comment: use switch or if/else condition for styles? can i insert directly into a css file? if i have for example 1000 line of style code and user use 10 line of style codes then the browser must load all codes and it takes time

Comment: you can use if/else if you are using 2 size only

Comment: and if i have a lot of various options? like ultimate shortcode plugin. what i do? what the solution way of this plugin

Comment: for lot of option you should use switch case